# How can I reliably inject values into instances created outside of my control?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I have a class `A` with a method `foo()` that behaves differently depending on some configuration value:

```
class A {
    private transient Config config; // How do I set this field?

    public int foo() {
        return config.hasKey("bar") ? 1 : 2;
    }
}
```

A persistence framework like Hibernate creates instances of `A`. How can I inject the current value of `config` into the instance?

Note: I'm using OJB, not Hibernate but the problem itself is always the same. It boils down to: I have some framework that creates instances for me. How can I reliably inject values into instances created outside of my control?

Performance is an issue here since millions of these objects are created.

Comment: Does ObJectRelationalBridge provide any [interceptors or events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) you can use to inject the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer is not exactly what you're looking for, Hibernate offers Interceptors for this type of processing. I'm not familiar with OJB, but you might find something similar.

> You can get Spring to inject your
>   services into your Hibernate
>   instantiated instances, using AOP. You
>   can also get Hibernate to do the same,
>   using Interceptors.
>
> See
>   http://www.jblewitt.com/blog/?p=129

Taken from a previous answer of mine

[Spring and the anemic domain model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304245/spring-and-the-anemic-domain-model/1304354#1304354)

Answer (score 0):

config is part of the state of each A? if that's true then the value must be stored by your ORM too.

Comment: Let's assume that this is not possible for some reason.

Comment: So given that the config is global for all the A's. Just create a class ConfigProvider or something, inject the Config inside it and call ConfigProvider.getConfig in your A default constructor.

Comment: That would work but it would also create a global variable. Any ideas how to do it without globals?

Comment: the config of each A is unique? or all of them share the same? There's no "global variable" the ConfigProvider is a singleton and gets the config injected by your DI mechanism of choice.

Comment: singleton is just another name for "global variable"; it breaks unit tests. :-)

Comment: the ConfigProvider is a SINGLETON and it don't have any state. It takes your configuration from wherever you have it and acts as a service layer. Anyway, if it breaks your unit tests you have to improve your mocking skills :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Just a thought... If it is for testing purpose, the easiest way is to mock `foo()` to return the value you want. If it is for production, then I might consider using AOP to intercept `foo()` and inject the value to it.</s>

Okay, now that I see your config is transient... :)

```
class A {
    private ConfigService configService;
    private transient Config config;

    public Config getConfig() {
        if (config == null) {
            config = configService.getConfig();
        }
        return config;
    }

    public int foo() {
        return getConfig().hasKey("bar") ? 1 : 2;
    }
}

class ConfigService {   
    // use this API to inject the value into config first
    public Config getConfig(...) { ... }
}
```

Will something like this work for you?

Comment: If you are using Spring, then you can easily wire a ConfigService singleton into class A. Otherwise, you will probably need to create a Factory that returns the ConfigService.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know ,if this is helpful .From `Hibernate EntityManager.`

```
long parentId = 12;
EntityManager em ... 
Parent parent = em.getReference(Parent.class, parentId);
parent.setFoo(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something like this in OJB, follow this pattern:

`RowReaderDefaultImpl` calls `ClassHelper.buildNewObjectInstance()` to create the objects it reads from the database. So you need to override `RowReaderDefaultImpl.buildOrRefreshObject()`. A property in `OJB.properties` allows you to inject your own implementation into the system.

Unfortunately, there is no way to override `ClassHelper.buildNewObjectInstance()` itself (it's `public static`).

`ClassHelper.buildNewObjectInstance()` is called in two more places:

`org.apache.ojb.broker.cache.ObjectCacheTwoLevelImpl.CopyStrategyImpl.read(PersistenceBroker, Object)` and `org.apache.ojb.broker.metadata.SuperReferenceDescriptor.SuperReferenceField.getObjectWithDeclaredSuperClass(Object)` Not sure what they do; our project doesn't need them.

If you need to override those two as well, you will have to patch the sources of OJB.